# Employee Scheduling - Allow Shifts not Assigned

Tags: timefold

I'm running a proof on concept to see if Timefold can cover the scenarios we have. So, all good, but, Timefold always find an Employee to all shifts, event when the `oneShiftPerDay` constraint is set, it always repeats someone and assigns them to the shift.
Is there a way to leave shifts unassigned?

My test case was simple:

- 3 staff
- 4 shifts (same day)
- `oneShiftPerDay` constraint ON
- Timefold Result: All 4 shifts assigned repeating one of the 3 staff.
- Desired Result: 3 shifts assigned, 1 unassigned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not enough to enable the constraint. You also need to tell the solver that it is *allowed* to leave some entities unassigned. Based on if you're using basic variables or list variables, the documentation will tell you more:

- [Allowing unassigned with basic variable](https://timefold.ai/docs/timefold-solver/latest/using-timefold-solver/modeling-planning-problems#planningVariableAllowingUnassigned).
- [Allowing unassigned with list variable](https://timefold.ai/docs/timefold-solver/latest/using-timefold-solver/modeling-planning-problems#planningListVariableAllowingUnassigned).

Also, without actually seeing your constraints, I can't really tell if the constraint perhaps doesn't do something that would make the solver prefer assigning the entities.